# Primitive elements of finite fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, primitive-roots, function-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number and $q=p^n$ for some positive integer $n$. $F_q[x]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients in $F_q$. For any $M(x)\in F_q[x]$, define $\mathcal{R}(M(x))\subset F_q[x]$ to be the set of all polynomials which has degree less than $M(x)$.

Fix $P(x)\in F_q[x]$, is there a sequence of functions $\{M_n(x)\}_{n\geq1}\subset F_q[x]$ such that $$\left\{P^i(x)(mod ~M_n(x)): i\in\mathbb{N}\right\}=\mathcal{R}(M(x))$$ for every $n\geq1?$

Fix $P(x),Q(x)\in F_q[x],(P(x),Q(x))=1$, is there a sequence of functions $\{M_n(x)\}_{n\geq1}\subset F_q[x]$ such that $$\left\{P^i(x)(mod ~M_n(x)): i\in\mathbb{N}\right\}=\mathcal{R}(M(x))$$ and $$\left\{Q^j(x)(mod ~M_n(x)): j\in\mathbb{N}\right\}=\mathcal{R}(M(x))$$ for every $n\geq1?$

I think this is about primitive element of finite fields. and I know that if

[$P(x)=x$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf)  (corollary2.3)

then the first quenstion is valid. But is the general case right?

Comment: Unless I misread I think the answer to your 1st question is affirmative for most polynomials $P(x)$. That is a theorem of Bilharz, but the result may be better known as *Artin's conjecture on primitive roots over function fields*. It is analogous to Artin's conjecture that a given non-square integer is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes. I need to locate my copy Michael Rosen's *Number theory in function fields* before I say anything precise. The details are there. I cannot say anything about the second question right away.

Comment: For example, when $p$ is odd, we obviously must exclude the case where $P(x)$ is the square of another polynomial (compare: a square cannot be a primitive root modulo an odd prime). I need to check whether other exceptions of this nature are needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Thank you for your hints. I have found Bilharz's theorem of Artin's conjecture in function field. And i will try to solve the second question then.